# How to create an event when you tap and hold the map?

Tags: iphone, mapkit

It works the same way in Maps.app: when you tap and hold for a second or two the app drops a pin there.

I'll attach a piece of code here (I need LongPress to work on annotations and it doesn't work in this code). Please consider helping.

```
MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:MeAnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
pinView.canShowCallout = NO;            
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showCountdown:)];
[pinView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
[longPressGesture release];
```

Comment: Have you started writing any code, or this just an idea at present?

Comment: @Dan Ray: Another problem appeared, can you please take a look at the code in the question body? The event doesn't fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can specify the time needed for it to fire. Dropping a pin there however is a matter of properly placing and animating an image, but giving you code for that would be doing pretty much all work for you instead of simply helping you with your problem?

Comment: Thank you, the Recognizer works fine but my app needs the LongPress to work on annotations. The following code does not work. Could you please consider helping us with the issue.

Comment: Sorry, getting used to code formatting here takes longer than I thought.

Comment: Code is posted into the question body. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure you set the properties on the recognizer. For example minimumPressDuration, numberOfTouchesRequired, etc.